# php speed vs. mysql speed

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm making a feeds aggregator using php and mysql. And writting a paper about it which **must** contain math.

I have a table `feeds` (id, title, description, link) where `id` is the primary key.
When I collect new feeds I need to add them to the database, but I must not let any duplicates in. I see two ways to do that:

1) for each feed run something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM feeds 
WHERE title=$feed.title AND description=$feed.description;
```

And see if it returns any feeds.

2) Assume that feeds which came from different sources never match. In this case:
for each source of feeds run something like this:

```
SELECT title, description, source FROM feeds WHERE source=$source;
```

Then use PHP to match collected feeds against this array.

I admit, I don't have any performance problem. But I'm writing a paper about it and I **must find some way to apply math** to the problem. I've choosen the second approach because it allows me to go into math details about why it can be faster.
But I suspect that php might do the work much slower then mysql would and it might actually be faster to run a query for each feed.

Am I right? Is there any practical reason to choose the second approach? How can I justify my choise?

Comment: Performance is usually not an issue until you have a sufficiently large set of data on which to perform your metrics. How many feeds/sources (rows of data/count of objects) are you measuring performance against?

Comment: yes, I don't have any performance problem. My problem is that **I need to apply math** so that I have something to write the paper about.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an artificial exercise in finding "some way to apply math to the problem," not an actual programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you considered using a composite unique index instead?

```
alter table feeds add unique index(title, description);
```

this would prevent adding new rows when title and description taken together are already present in the table.

you would have to do large number of inserts in a large database to really get performance values though.

Edit:
This does have one downfall in MYSQL Null is always considered unique so you could have several rows input that are title=null and description=null.  You should check for this before attempting insert of data.

Comment: yes, but I need to write the paper and to do so I must find a way to apply math. Also, accorsing to RSS specs title and description can't both be null.

Comment: This may be of use at some point.
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/01/sample-datasets-for-benchmarking-and-testing/

Comment: Bad idea. You do not want long key lengths as they will make indexing far slower.

Comment: Everything is a trade off. is the performance hit greater by utilizing the index than doing a query against the database to see if the row exists then doing a separate insert based on the success or failure of that query?

Comment: I accept this because it provides the best solution as far as I can see. Though it doesn't really solve my problem with finding where to apply the math or justifying the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the math, consider what the scaling implications are for your database.  How long does an add of a new feed take for the first feed?  How about the 10,000th?  What about the 10 millionth?  In what way does the increase in number of existing feeds affect the speed by which a new feed can be added?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this because it's the most relevant answer to the questions I actually asked. It doesn't help though since what I need is to justify my decisions with math rather then simply research anything related to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and MySQL: Both running in the Serverside, not like javascript in clientside/Browser.

If you do not have more then millions of data, it wont be slow anyway.

Comment: yes, but I need to write the paper and to do so I must find a way to apply math.

Answer (score 0):

why not just add a index that is unique on title and description? don't know if its the best to do performance wise but it will handle the logic for you in the most correct way..

Comment: because I won't have anything to write the paper about

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way would be to put a UNIQUE index on the source column, and simply do an INSERT IGNORE, sending all your collected feeds in one query without even manually checking for duplicates.  Not only will this save you the processing/network overhead of doing one query per feed, the index will ensure you don't have any duplicates (assuming source is actually unique per feed).